# 403 When Bucket Policy IP Address Condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What I am trying to do is restrict access to a file to a single IP address.

The bucket policy belows works only when either `0.0.0.0/0` is used instead of the actual IP address or the condition is removed, otherwise a `403 (Forbidden)` error is served.

The IP address is confirmed to be `68.6N.NN1.1N2`.

**I recieve a `200` response if I send a curl request via terminal. However, if I include a direct link to the object in `index.php`, the response is a `403 (Forbidden)` error...**

*(I have zero experience with cloud platforms. Any help would be very much appreciated.)*

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy17NN310NN0610",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt171NN106NN335",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket/file.jpg",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "68.6N.NN1.1N2"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Screenshot Confirming the IP Address**

[image: IP Address Confirmation]

**Screenshot Showing a `200` Response to a cURL Request**

[image: Response to Terminal cURL Request]

Comment: Can you please clarify your actual objective? Are you wanting any requests from that IP address to be able to download that specific object without providing credentials, or are you wanting **users** who are accessing a website hosted on that server to be able to see the image in a web page _served_ by that server? If it is the first option, how is the server accessing the object and why are you not choosing to connect via an authenticated method? After all, if it is a shared server it means that other shared servers will be able to access the object too.

Comment: Shared hosting might mean that the IP is dynamic and not static. You could try a CIDR range such as 68.6N.NN1.1N3/24 or a single IP 68.6N.NN1.1N3/32.

Comment: Ah! That could be it @Sflagg -- it probably needs the `/32` at the end: `68.6N.NN1.1N3/32`

Comment: @JohnRotenstein whoops. i am trying to allow only a single IP address access to the file

Comment: @Sflagg still no dice. i asked the shared hosting support if the IP address is static or dynamic and they responded by saying "In your case, it is static..."

Comment: might the issue have something to do with the fact that theres no SSL cert on the client or my shared hosting website?

Comment: I suggest you test the situation by changing the IP address to `0.0.0.0/0`. This should work. You can then narrow-down the IP address to find out what it _really_ is. If you can SSH into the instance, you can then use `curl https://icanhazip.com/` to discover what IP address the server 'appears' to be coming from.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein ill test `0.0.0.0/0`, but what does this do exactly? does it permit requests from any ip address? are there not log files somewhere in S3 so that i can check which IP address is requesting the file?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein similar to removing the condition altogether, theres no problems when i use `0.0.0.0/0`. do you know where are the S3 logs are located so that i can check the logs to see which IP address is making the request?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein if a curl request is sent via the shared hosting SSH, then i get a `200` response -.-a so must be something with the way the shared hosting server is set up?

Comment: The problem is that you don't actually know what IP address is being used when the server requests the file from S3. The fact that it works with `0.0.0.0/0` (which represents the whole Internet) means that everything is configured correctly -- you just need to find the actual IP address that is being used by the server. That's why I was recommending that you SSH into the server then run `curl https://icanhazip.com/`. It will display the IP address from which the request is coming. You can then use that IP address with `/32` at the end.

Comment: Yes, you could [Log requests with server access logging - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ServerLogs.html) but it takes a while for the logs to come through, whereas the `curl` test is immediate. By the way, the "proper" way to do all this is to give your server a set of credentials to retrieve the object rather than opening a 'hole' to allow a specific IP address to get access.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein i ran the `curl https://icanhazip.com/` command and its returning the IP address that i was using already, `68.6N.NN1.1N2` -.-a / ah, can u send me a link to the documentation that talks about the "proper" way to do this. id still like to figure out why the IP address condition does not work haha

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks john! ill notify u once the bounty is over

Comment: If you include a direct link in index.php and serve it on a webpage, then people are sending requests to S3 using their own IP addresses instead of your server's IP. In other words, from S3's perspective, requests are not coming from your server, and they are coming from the internet.

Comment: @jellycsc ahh im gonna smack my head against the wall if this resolves it

Comment: @jellycsc u were right.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein hey john, bountys finished. thx again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, there is some confusion about how the S3 bucket policy interacts with the way the file is being accessed.

```bash
User's Browser
      |
      v
+------------+   request for file   +--------+    IP-based restriction    +----------+
| index.php  | -------------------> | AWS S3 | <------------------------- |  cPanel  |
| on Server  |    (client's IP)     | Bucket |    (server's IP allowed)   | Terminal |
+------------+                      +--------+                            +----------+
```

Expanding on [jellycsc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10692493/jellycsc)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78157861/403-when-bucket-policy-ip-address-condition#comment137814128_78157861), the issue could be with the IP address seen by AWS when a user tries to access the file through `index.php` on a website. AWS is seeing the IP address of the user's browser, not the server's IP address. Since the bucket policy is set to only allow access from a single IP address (the server's), requests coming from any other IP address (like a user's browser) will be denied with a 403 error.

The fact that `curl https://icanhazip.com/` returns the expected IP address suggests that your server is using the correct IP. But again, if `index.php` includes a direct link to the object and the browser tries to fetch it, AWS will see the request as coming from the client's IP address, not the server's.

If you want the object to be accessible only from the server's IP, you will need to make sure that the server itself fetches the object and then serves it to the client. That would involve a server-side script that handles the download and then serves the file to the client, rather than the client directly requesting the file from S3 ([`S3Client`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#___construct) + [`S3.getObject()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#getobject)).

```php
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

$s3Client = new S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'your-region-1',
    // 'credentials' => // if needed, though it is better to use IAM roles
]);

$bucketName = 'testbucket';
$fileKey = 'file.jpg';

try {
    // Get the object from S3
    $result = $s3Client->getObject([
        'Bucket' => $bucketName,
        'Key'    => $fileKey,
    ]);

    // Set appropriate header for the file content
    header("Content-Type: {$result['ContentType']}");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($fileKey) . '"');
    header('Content-Length: ' . $result['ContentLength']);

    // Output the file content
    echo $result['Body'];
} catch (AwsException $e) {
    // Handle error accordingly
    echo "Error fetching file: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Here, when a user requests `index.php`, the server itself requests the object from S3 using its AWS credentials, and then passes it on to the user, without exposing the direct link to S3. The bucket policy IP restriction should work as expected because AWS only sees the server's IP address.

---

> All I want to do is get the S3 bucket to respect its own policy so that I can quickly test something... I might not even need/want to use AWS at the end of the day. But I do need to restrict by IP address alone.

It is true, the above script bypasses IP-based restrictions entirely by using AWS SDK for PHP to access the file with IAM credentials.

If you need to test IP-based access restrictions without involving IAM roles or AWS SDK authentication, you would need to make sure the IP address in the S3 bucket policy is correct and that requests to S3 are actually coming from that IP address.

And... you might *already* have conducted the test regarding IP-based restrictions through direct links in `index.php`. A `403 Forbidden` error when accessing the S3 object through a web page—accurately reflects the situation where the S3 bucket policy restricts access to a specific IP address (presumably the server's), and the requests come from different client IP addresses through the browser.

So that confirms the behavior expected under such a policy configuration: direct access attempts from any IP address other than the one specified in the policy will result in access being denied.

---

As noted by [John Rotenstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174777/john-rotenstein) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78157861/403-when-bucket-policy-ip-address-condition/78172222#comment137818244_78172222):

> If you want the user's browser to fetch the object, then either the object needs to be 'public' or you can use a pre-signed URL to grant temporary access to a private object.

True: if the goal is to allow a user's browser to fetch the object directly, without going through server-side processing, there are two main strategies to consider:

- The simplest approach (but also the least secure) is to allow anyone with the link to access the file. That method should only be used if the object does not contain sensitive information and is intended to be publicly accessible. [Update the object's permissions to grant read access to "Everyone"](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket).
- Use a [pre-signed URL for the S3 object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html): it provides time-limited access to a private object, using the server's credentials to generate a URL that includes a signature. That signature authorizes the request as if the server itself is making the request, but it can be used directly by the user's browser.

  ```php
  require 'vendor/autoload.php';

  use Aws\S3\S3Client;
  use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

  $s3Client = new S3Client([
      'version' => 'latest',
      'region'  => 'your-region-1',
      'credentials' => [
          'key'    => 'YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
          'secret' => 'YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
      ],
  ]);

  $bucketName = 'testbucket';
  $fileKey = 'file.jpg';

  // Set expiration time for the URL
  $cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
      'Bucket' => $bucketName,
      'Key'    => $fileKey
  ]);

  $request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes'); // URL expires in 20 minutes

  $presignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();

  echo "Pre-Signed URL: " . $presignedUrl;
  ```

  That URL can be safely shared with users, granting them temporary access to the private object.

Comment: ah ok i wasnt using php to fetch the the resource, so i will test this (without using the AWS SDK for PHP and IAM credentials if its possible to do so). i suspect youre right and this will work.

Comment: yep this was the issue and the test i had devised is nonsensical because i misunderstood this *facepalm*

Comment: If you want the user's browser to fetch the object, then either the object needs to be 'public' or you can use a pre-signed URL to grant temporary access to a private object.

Comment: @oldboy I have edited the answer to include an example illustrating John's comment.

Comment: s3 to server was sufficient for me, but that could be useful to somebody!

Answer (score 3):

The 'preferred' method would be:

- Keep the Amazon S3 bucket **private**, with no Bucket Policy
- Create an **IAM User** for the application running on the hosting server
- Grant **permissions** to the IAM User to grant it access to the appropriate bucket and prefixes
- The application **uses an [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/developer/tools/) to access the file**, or it constructs an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which provides time-limited access to private objects in Amazon S3

This way, access is **authenticated** rather than relying on the request coming from a specific IP address, especially since that IP address is potentially shared with systems not under your control.

Comment: unfortunately, for what im trying to build, i cant grant time-limited access to the objects to a given client :( the IP address that was identified isnt necessarily the shared address, but the "virtual" public address that nobody else on the server has access to (so the only thing i have to worry about this way is IP spoofing, but i plan to enhance security another way in the future. just need to test something right now, which is proving impossible haha)

Comment: Hey @oldboy John works for AWS and is giving pro advice. He mentions you can create Pre-Signed Urls (same as Shared Access Signatures in Azure) and *are* time-limited with an expiry. However Jonn's primary response was to create an IAM user with access to the Bucket. So create a Role with access to the Bucket, then create a User with programmatic access and you'll get credentials (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/file-format.html - see last paragraph for eg) to put in a file in the aws folder (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/file-location.html) *not* time-limited

Comment: @JeremyThompson all i want to do is get the S3 bucket to respect its own policy so that i can quickly test something... i might not even need/want to use AWS at the end of the day. but i do need to restrict by IP address alone

Comment: @JeremyThompson i go to create an IAM user now and AWS itself recommends doing so only if you want to grant programmatic access, which is not needed or desired...

Comment: In this case, programmatic access is exactly what you should be using. It's a bit like saying you'd like to give one person access to your house. One option is to give them a key so that they can enter but nobody else can. Or, you can open a window and say "anyone entering from this direction is allowed in". That makes it less secure than giving a key. Anyway, I still think it likely that the problem with the policy is that it isn't using the IP address that the server is actually using, or it isn't in the right format (eg `x.x.x.x/32`).

Comment: fair enough, but i dont understand why everything identifies my IP as the given IP, except the S3 bucket. ive tried using the subnet prefix too, but no dice with that either. anyways, im gonna put a bounty on this cuz i need to run this test